# How do I convert my Django app to use form validation correctly using Django forms?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have an existing application that works as it exists. As of right now, I obtain data from a POST request, retrieve it one by one, and then perform some logic. Here is some of my existing code:

```py
last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
mi = request.POST.get('mi')
street_line1 = request.POST.get('street_line1')
#sanitize
if last_name == None:
  return HttpResponse("Invalid last name.", status=422)
if first_name == None:
  return HttpResponse("Invalid first name.", status=422)
if street_line1 == None:
  return HttpResponse("Invalid address line 1.", status=422)

street_line2 = request.POST.get('street_line2')
street_line3 = request.POST.get('street_line3')
city = request.POST.get('city')
# sanitize
if city == None:
  return HttpResponse("Invalid city.", status=422)
```

etc. For each field in my model, I pull it manually, then do some sanitization (which, for most of my fields, is simply making them required.) Once I pull all of my data, I grab some things from my JWT, and the primary key from my POST request, then I do some logic to determine if the primary key (surrogate_id) already exists. If it does, I update the data. If it does not, I create a new instance in the db. This happens like so:

```py
# Grab the pidm from the JWT
user_pidm = Identity.objects.get(username=payload['username']).pidm
# grab the surrogate_id
sur_id = Contact.objects.filter(surrogate_id=surrogate_id)
# Check if the query returned anything
if len(sur_id) < 1:
  user_exists = False
else:
  entry = sur_id[0] # Save it for use later
  user_exists = True

# Use the user_exists flag to add to the database
if user_exists:
  # print("user exists")
  entry.pidm = user_pidm
  entry.priority = priority
  entry.relt_code = relt_code
  entry.last_name = last_name
  entry.first_name = first_name
  entry.mi = mi
  entry.street_line1 = street_line1
  entry.street_line2 = street_line2
  entry.street_line3 = street_line3
  entry.city = city
  entry.stat_code = stat_code
  entry.natn_code = natn_code
  entry.zip = zip
  entry.ctry_code_phone = ctry_code_phone
  entry.phone_area = phone_area
  entry.phone_number = phone_number
  entry.phone_ext = phone_ext
  # Save after writing to database
  entry.save()
  return HttpResponse("Emergency Contact Updated")
else:
  # Add the user (questions regarding usage of PIDM vs Surrogate)
  # print("Adding new user")
  n_entry = Contact(
        surrogate_id=surrogate_id,
        pidm=user_pidm,
        priority=priority,
        relt_code=relt_code,
        last_name=last_name,
        first_name=first_name,
        mi=mi,
        street_line1=street_line1,
        street_line2=street_line2,
        street_line3=street_line3,
        city=city,
        stat_code=stat_code,
        natn_code=natn_code,
        zip=zip,
        ctry_code_phone=ctry_code_phone,
        phone_area=phone_area,
        phone_number=phone_number,
        phone_ext=phone_ext)
  n_entry.save()

  return HttpResponse("New user added")
```

Now, I am trying to make this more elegant using forms. I set up a forms.py file with the following code (which models my database model)

```py
class UpdateEmergencyContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Provide an example of the schema of the model
    surrogate_id = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    priority = forms.CharField()
    relt_code = forms.CharField(max_length=4)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=240)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=240)
    mi = forms.CharField(max_length=240, required=False, null=True)

    street_line1 = forms.CharField(max_length=300)
    street_line2 = forms.Charfield(max_length=300, required=False, null=True)
    street_line3 = forms.Charfield(max_length=300, required=False, null=True)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    stat_code = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    natn_code = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    zip = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    ctry_code_phone = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    phone_area = forms.CharField(max_length=24)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=48)
    phone_ext = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False, null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = [
            'surrogate_id', 'priority', 'relt_code',
            'last_name', 'first_name', 'mi',
            'street_line1', 'street_line2', 'street_line3',
            'city', 'stat_code', 'natn_code', 'zip',
            'ctry_code_phone', 'phone_area', 'phone_number', 'phone_ext'
        ]

    def clean_phone_number(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #validation function goes here
        phone_area = self.cleaned_data.get("phone_area")
        phone_num = self.cleaned_data.get("phone_num")

        full_phone = phone_area + phone_num
        result = sanitization.validate_phone_num(full_phone)
        if result:
            return full_phone
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid phone number")

    def clean_relt_code(self, *args, **kwargs):
        valid_relational_codes = ['G', 'F', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'A', 'R']
        relation_code = self.cleaned_data.get("relt_code")
        if relation_code in valid_relational_codes:
            return relation_code
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid relation code")
```

Now, I am getting confused as to how I integrate this into my views.py. I know that, instead of all of those calls to request.POST.get() in my first code snippet, I can simply say

```
form = UpdateEmergencyContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = UpdateEmergencyContactForm()
```

But I am lost as to how to integrate the remainder of the logic. I need to check if the p-key exists, and if it does, update the DB, and if not then create a new entry. Would this logic simply go into the "if form.is_valid()" code block? How much of my original code would I need to replace with the form validation Django API?

Comment: how you get the `p-key` ? did you pass it as one of POST req param?

Comment: I get it from the Form data. That’s the logic I need to implement. If the p key is missing from the form then it’s a “create entry”, if it is present it is a “update entry with following p-key” and I am unsure how to implement this in my form logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you get the primarykey from `request.POST`, first you have to query the db to get the relevant db entry and then you should pass it as value for `instance` kwarg.

If the returned instance value is `None`, the corresponding form should create a new entry else it should update the existing one.

```
instance = Model.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['pkey']).first()
form = UpdateEmergencyContactForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('success_url')
return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

Comment: What if I want to append a data value to my form before I call form.save()? Would I be able to? Let's say my database model has a IntegerField called "sumnum" and this is not passed with my post request, but rather created in my program. If I call form.save() and the form did not receive a sumnum field, it gives me an error (considering sumnum is required in the DB, stating NOT NULL constraint failed). How can I append my created sumnum to my form before saving it?

Comment: Just pass sumnum filed and it's Val to initial kwarg. Ie. On form initialisation, you have to add initial kwarg.on the  (instance=instance, initial={'sumnum':4})

Comment: For this to work, you have to include sumnum field on modelform meta.

Answer (score 0):

form.is_valid will validade everything for you, based on the information you gave on UpdateEmergencyContactForm. Including your pk that is incremented as default. You don't need to set anything.

If you want to change the error message you can do something like:

```
first_name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please let us know what to call you!'})
```